# Reversing a Boolean stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a button that toggles dark mode.
I store the dark mode state as Boolean in localStorage.

The button invokes this function that should flip the Boolean, 
but it isn't working.

```
const handleDarkMode = () => {
  let darkMode = localStorage.darkMode
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", !darkMode)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Items in local storage are stored as strings, thus you need to turn your `"true"`/`"false"` values into `true`/`false` (boolean) values before you can use `darkMode` as a boolean:

```
const handleDarkMode = () => {
  let darkMode = localStorage.darkMode === "true"; // change "true" to true and others to false
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", !darkMode)
}
```

*Also note:* In general to get an item from localStorage we use `getItem(key)`

Comment: Thank you and the others. Both suggestions working.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage converts Boolean to String, so you need to check it like that.

```
const handleDarkMode = () => {
  let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'true';
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', !darkMode);
}
```